# after storing an object in session, it is automatically updated in session when object is changed. Why?

Tags: php, session

I found this interesting behavior in PHP. I can't understand why the object in session is getting updated even though I'm not explicitly storing it in session after it's been manipulated.

Can someone please enlighten me?

While the snippet below is written using Laravel 4 framework, the underlying session-related behavior is a function of PHP. Example code:

```
Route::get('/', function()
{
    $stored = Session::get('testing');

    if (!$stored)
    {
        $stored = new StdClass;
        $stored->counter = 0;
        Session::set('testing', $stored);
    }

    $stored->counter ++;

    // Session::set('testing', $stored);
    // if the above line were NOT commented out, i could understand why the counter keeps on increasing.

    var_dump($stored->counter);
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since PHP objects are passed by reference (since PHP 5.0) and session write (if not executed directly with **session_write_close()** function) happens after script execution it is expected behavior from PHP itself.

So it goes as follows (I am not really speaking how exactly it goes in Laravel itself, but more in PHP's internals) :

1. You write object into SESSION
2. You change the object state
3. Scripts ends and write to a file happens with object changed state.

So if object is stored in session - always the latest object's state is written into session file.